# Date Time Not Shown as NaN on Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, mobile-safari

Learning JS and have worked out how to make a simple countdown. Issue is I recently changed to countdown until datetime rather than just date, and now iOS Safari shows the countdown as "NaN" seconds left etc. and I can't work out why. (See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRA6S.png))

Date is pulled out of sql db in php the only js im using on this page is for the countdown timer.
Code is below.

```
<script>
// Set date to countdown til
var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $dbDate; ?>").getTime();

// Update every second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get current date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Calculate distance between then and now
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output result with id="countdown"
  document.getElementById("countdown-top").innerHTML = days + "d : " + hours + "h";
  document.getElementById("countdown-bottom").innerHTML = minutes + "m : " + seconds + "s ";

  // If countdown ended show text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown-top").innerHTML = "Coutdown Has Ended,";
    document.getElementById("countdown-bottom").innerHTML = "Not Long Left!";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example value of `$dbDate`? seems like the format can't be parsed by Safari.

Comment: @JoanPicornell 
$dbDate is equal to the string "2020-10-15 19:30:00"

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that `$dbDate` is provided in a format that Safari isn't able to parse. As per other issues on StackOverflow, I'd suggest you to use [date-fns library](https://date-fns.org/). Being more specific, using the [parse function](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/parse) of that library. This library have another useful utilities that I think will fit your code and make it more readable.

You can try also providing a format that Safari could understand, which probably is ISO8601. You'll have to change that in PHP so `$dbDate` is a valid ISO date. That could work for some Safari versions, but I'd recommend you to use a library such as date-fns, so you'll have a broader browser support.

Comment: I've reformatted the date to ISO for the time being and it has fixed the issue on modern safari. I'll learn how to use the date-fns libaray now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. If you think it's the correct answer, mark it as such so other people can find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the php date in ISO8601 fixed NaN value for me.
You can do it with the following

```
$convert_date = date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime($your_date));
```

Comment: it's helpful to wrap code in back ticks ``like this``

Comment: You are right. Done!